# How to copy files from android device to OpenBSD

Tags: mount, android, openbsd, bsd

Here is what `dmesg | tail` shows after I connect my android phone to the USB port (the last three lines show up when I turn on USB tethering on the android device):

```
# dmesg | tail
vscsi0 at root
scsibus2 at vscsi0: 256 targets
softraid0 at root
scsibus3 at softraid0: 256 targets
root on sd0a (0f8bf9d33b04be52.a) swap on sd0b dump on sd0b
iwm0: hw rev 0x200, fw ver 16.242414.0, address 44:85:00:ab:46:09
ugen2 at uhub0 port 2 "motorola MotoG3" rev 2.00/ff.ff addr 5
ugen2 detached
urndis0 at uhub0 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "motorola MotoG3" rev 2.00/ff.ff addr 5
urndis0: using RNDIS, address 02:69:60:0b:0a:00
```

This is what `disklabel` shows:

```
# disklabel urndis0    
disklabel: /dev/rurndis0: No such file or directory
# disklabel ugen2   
disklabel: /dev/rugen2: No such file or directory
```

How do I mount (or copy files from) the android phone? I am a new BSD (OpenBSD 6.2) user.

Comment: Not too familiar with BSD, but `urndis0` is a network interface, so at best you can make a network connection. Then you need demons/applications that allow file copying over the network. Can't you switch your Android to a mode where it appears as an USB storage device?

Comment: @dirkt The last three lines appeared because of me turning on USB tethering. If I don't turn on USB tethering, the last three lines are not printed. But, even then `disklabel` is not able to work with `ugen2`. BTW, I don't know what `ugen2` is. Does `ugen2` indicate that my android device is appearing as an USB storage device before I turn on USB tethering?

Comment: Googling shows that `ugen` is a generic USB interface, not a disk, so again, `disklabel` won't work with it. I'm not familiar enough with BSD to know how to find out details on USB devices. Some Android phones offer access to files via [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), but I've no idea what applications are there for that on BSD. On Linux, you've several choices.

Answer (score 3):

Theory:

- You do not need `disklabel` ! It is used to create BSD partitions inside of PC(MBR) partition (slice in terms of BSD)
- There are 2 types of USB storage protocols:
- - USB Mass Device. Block device (flash, external drive) and it is fully supported by `umass(4)` driver.
- - MTP device. It works in terms of files, not blocks and it is not supported by OpenBSD kernel, so OpenBSD can only say thay you have some general USB device (`ugen(4)`) which means you need some user tool to access it.

Good news is there is a port of Linux `simple-mtpfs` which works like FUSE: file system running in user space: http://ports.su/sysutils/simple-mtpfs . And OpenBSD has `fuse(4)`.

Practice (just tried it with my Andorid and OpenBSD 6.3):

- `pkg_add simple-mtpfs`
- `mtp-connect`
- `simple-mtpfs /mnt && cd /mnt/ && ls`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gmtp` https://gmtp.sourceforge.io

It requires `libmtp libid3tag flac`

Comment: Show an example of the commands usage.